# Call to undefined function get_term_meta

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a very small problem. I hope someone could enlighten me why this is giving me this error. I have here my function that displays the url of the image of one of my category under my custom taxonomy called 'item_category'. this is under functions.php

```
function list_all_categories(){

$categories = get_term( 2 ,'item_category' );
$src = get_term_meta(2,'javo_item_category_featured',true);

echo $src;

}
add_shortcode( 'list','list_all_categories' );
```

Comment: Do you have a function named `get_term_meta()`?

Comment: @JayBlanchard get_term_meta() is a wordpress function right? I just don't understand why it's not defined.

Comment: Which version of wordpress you use? This function released only in 4.4.0

Comment: The file having `get_term_meta()` (taxonomy.php) has to be included in the PHP file from which you're calling the function. Have you done that?

Comment: @maximkou my wordpress version is 4.2.6 *facepalm*

Comment: @carlzzz, update wordpress or use other function))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must update your Wordpress to have access to the get_term_meta function since you're runing version 4.2.6 but it's released on 4.4.0.

You can see it in the documentation here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/

If you don't want to update for whatever reason, the source of the function:

```
function get_term_meta( $term_id, $key = '', $single = false ) {
    // Bail if term meta table is not installed.
    if ( get_option( 'db_version' ) < 34370 ) {
        return false;
    }

    return get_metadata( 'term', $term_id, $key, $single );
}
```